# Изменении цвета svg img , без js

Tags: html, css, html5, svg

Можно ли изменить цвет svg

```
fill:#000;
```

Не используя js , средствами `CSS` или `SVG`

```html
   <img class="svg test1" src="https://web.archive.org/web/20210927151058/https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32441.svg">
```

Comment: а чего не закинуть svg и предохранится этой штукой https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: Внутрь картинки вставленной через `<img src="">` залезть нельзя никак.

Comment: Посмотрите второй ответ, - покраска CSS фильтрами. Хоть они и уступают по функиональности svg фильтрам, но их вполне можно успешно применять.

Answer (score 5):

Когда файл SVG добавлен на страницу HTML с помощью тега `<img>`, то он ничем не отличается от обычного изображения растрового формата. Поэтому невозможно применить стили из внешней таблицы `fill="red"`.

[image]

Но есть возможность изменить цвет фигур svg с помощью фильтров CSS или SVG.

Цвет SVG фильтра можно установить любой.

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#d3d3d3;
overflow:hidden;

}
.container:hover {
  background: black;
}
img {
  filter: url(#filter_B);
}
img:hover {
  filter: url(#filter_G);
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://web.archive.org/web/20210927151058/https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32441.svg">
</div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">  
    <defs>
       <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_G">
         <feFlood flood-color="yellowgreen"/>
         <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
      </filter>   
        <filter x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" id="filter_B">
           <feFlood flood-color="dodgerblue"/>
           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="xor" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

**2. Покрасить иконки в разные цвета при наведении, используя фильтр `feColorMatrix`**

```css
.R1:hover {
filter:url(#RedFilter);
} 

.G1:hover {
filter:url(#GreenFilter);
}
.B1:hover {
filter:url(#BlueFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="150" viewBox="0 -30 400 150" style="border:1px solid grey;"> 

  <defs>
 <filter id="RedFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="150" height="150">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    <filter id="GreenFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    
    <filter id="BlueFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 0 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter> 
    
    <filter id="WhiteFilter" x="-20" y="-20" width="140" height="140">
        <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                values="0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                        0 0 0 1 0
                "/>
    </filter>
 


   <image id="Building" width="100" height="100"  xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>   
   </defs> 
    
   <use class="R1" id="BuildingRed" xlink:href="#Building" x="20" y="0"   ></use> 
   <use class="G1" id="BuildingGreen" xlink:href="#Building" x="150" y="0"  ></use> 
    <use class="B1" id="BuildingBlue" xlink:href="#Building" x="280" y="0"  ></use>
   
   
</svg>
```

**3. Покрасить иконки в разные цвета при наведении, используя комбинацию фильтров `feComposite`, `feBlend`**

```css
.icon {
width:25vw; 
filter:url(#solid);
}
.icon:hover {
filter:url(#solid2);
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img class="icon" src="https://web.archive.org/web/20210927151058/https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32441.svg">
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1" height="1" > 

    <defs>
   <filter id="solid" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" >
     <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="dodgerblue" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="lighten" />
  </filter> 
    <!-- Фильтр работает при наведении-->
   <filter id="solid2" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" >
     <feFlood result="flood" flood-color="crimson" />
    <feComposite in="flood" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="maskedflood"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="maskedflood" mode="lighten" />
  </filter>
    
     </defs>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: работает криво в сафари

Answer (score 2):

Да, сконвертируйте свое `svg` изображение в код, вставьте в `html` не через `img`, а через `svg`. И уже для элементов внутри `svg` можете задавать цвет, обводку, шрифт и пр.

Answer (score 1):

### CSS фильтры

Внешний svg файл добавлен с помощью `background-image`
Для покраски иконок применены CSS фильтры:

```css
.twa-arrow {
  background-image: url("https://twemoji.maxcdn.com/svg/1f500.svg");
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  margin: 0 0.15em 0 0.3em;
  vertical-align: -0.3em;
  background-size: 3em 3em;
}
.grey-out {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.hue-rotate {
  filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
.invert {
  filter: invert(100%);
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <span class="twa-arrow"></span>
  <span class="twa-arrow grey-out"></span>
  <span class="twa-arrow hue-rotate"></span>
  <span class="twa-arrow invert"></span>
</body>
```