# Как изменить цвет svg?

Tags: html, css, html5, svg, filter

Как можно изменить цвет загруженного svg?

Я загружаю его с помощью `object`

```
<span>
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="css/image/Vector.svg"></object> УСЛУГИ
</span>
```

в css я пытаюсь поменять цвет таким образом

```
.services span:hover object {fill: #009091;}
```

В итоге ничего не происходит. В чем я допускаю ошибку?

Сам svg

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="86" height="86" viewBox="0 0 86 86" fill="none">
<path d="M9.86884 78.9508H8.459V80.3607H9.86884V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M15.5082 78.9508H14.0983V80.3607H15.5082V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M21.1475 78.9508H19.7377V80.3607H21.1475V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M77.541 78.9508H67.6722V80.3607H77.541V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M6.34426 86C2.8373 86 0 83.1627 0 79.6557V73.3115H2.81967V26.082C2.81967 22.575 5.65697 19.7377 9.16393 19.7377H33.8361V19.0328C33.8361 8.52951 42.3656 0 52.8689 0C63.3721 0 71.9016 8.52951 71.9016 19.0328V19.7377H76.8361C80.343 19.7377 83.1803 22.575 83.1803 26.082V73.3115H86V79.6557C86 83.1627 83.1627 86 79.6557 86H6.34426ZM1.40984 79.6557C1.40984 82.3697 3.63033 84.5902 6.34426 84.5902H79.6557C82.3697 84.5902 84.5902 82.3697 84.5902 79.6557V74.7213H76.1311V26.7869H70.2275L70.0336 27.1922C68.5004 30.3996 66.1213 33.1135 63.143 35.0344C60.0766 37.0258 56.5344 38.0656 52.8689 38.0656C49.2033 38.0656 45.6611 37.0258 42.5947 35.0344C39.6164 33.1135 37.2197 30.3996 35.7041 27.1922L35.5102 26.7869H9.86885V73.3115H32.0209L32.2324 73.5229C33.9242 75.2148 36.1623 76.1311 38.5414 76.1311H47.4762C49.8553 76.1311 52.0934 75.1971 53.7852 73.5229L53.9967 73.3115H71.9016V74.7213H54.5783L54.3844 74.8975C52.4988 76.607 50.0492 77.541 47.4939 77.541H38.559C36.0037 77.541 33.5541 76.607 31.6684 74.8975L31.4746 74.7213H1.40984V79.6557ZM71.6902 21.7467C71.5492 22.716 71.3553 23.6324 71.1086 24.4607L70.8443 25.3594H75.4262C76.5893 25.3594 77.541 26.3111 77.541 27.4742V73.2939H81.7705V26.082C81.7705 23.368 79.55 21.1475 76.8361 21.1475H71.7607L71.6902 21.7467ZM9.16393 21.1475C6.45 21.1475 4.22951 23.368 4.22951 26.082V73.3115H8.45902V27.4918C8.45902 26.3287 9.41066 25.377 10.5738 25.377H34.9111L34.6467 24.4783C34.4 23.6324 34.2061 22.7512 34.0652 21.7643L33.9771 21.1652H9.16393V21.1475ZM36.0918 13.6402C35.5279 15.4025 35.2459 17.2176 35.2459 19.0328C35.2459 28.743 43.1586 36.6557 52.8689 36.6557C54.2258 36.6557 55.618 36.4795 57.0279 36.1447L57.768 35.9684L52.3049 19.5615L36.3385 12.9L36.0918 13.6402ZM53.6795 19.2266L59.1074 35.5279L59.8123 35.2283C66.2975 32.4262 70.4918 26.082 70.4918 19.0328C70.4918 14.8914 69.0115 10.8381 66.3152 7.66598L65.8217 7.08443L53.6795 19.2266ZM52.8689 1.40984C46.2779 1.40984 40.2861 5.05779 37.2373 10.9262L36.8848 11.6135L52.7102 18.2045L64.8348 6.07992L64.2533 5.58648C61.0635 2.89016 57.0102 1.40984 52.8689 1.40984Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M43 69.082C41.0614 69.082 39.4754 67.4959 39.4754 65.5574C39.4754 65.293 39.5106 65.0111 39.5987 64.6938L39.7221 64.218L32.8139 59.6184L32.4086 59.918C31.7918 60.3762 31.0692 60.6229 30.3114 60.6229C29.5537 60.6229 28.8311 60.3762 28.2143 59.918L27.809 59.6184L20.9008 64.218L21.0242 64.6938C21.1123 65.0111 21.1475 65.293 21.1475 65.5574C21.1475 67.4959 19.5614 69.082 17.6229 69.082C15.6844 69.082 14.0983 67.4959 14.0983 65.5574C14.0983 63.6189 15.6844 62.0328 17.6229 62.0328C18.3807 62.0328 19.1033 62.2795 19.7201 62.7377L20.1254 63.0373L27.0336 58.4377L26.9102 57.9619C26.8221 57.6447 26.7869 57.3627 26.7869 57.0984C26.7869 55.1598 28.3729 53.5738 30.3114 53.5738C32.25 53.5738 33.836 55.1598 33.836 57.0984C33.836 57.3627 33.8008 57.627 33.7127 57.9619L33.5893 58.4377L40.4975 63.0373L40.9028 62.7377C41.5196 62.2795 42.2598 62.0328 43 62.0328C43.6344 62.0328 44.2864 62.2266 44.8504 62.5791L45.2733 62.8434L53.9438 55.9L53.7852 55.4242C53.6442 55.0189 53.5737 54.6488 53.5737 54.2787C53.5737 52.3402 55.1598 50.7541 57.0983 50.7541C59.0369 50.7541 60.6229 52.3402 60.6229 54.2787C60.6229 54.5959 60.5701 54.9307 60.4467 55.3184L60.3057 55.7943L66.0155 60.0766L66.4385 59.7947C67.0201 59.407 67.6897 59.1955 68.3946 59.1955C70.3332 59.1955 71.9192 60.7816 71.9192 62.7201C71.9192 64.6586 70.3332 66.2447 68.3946 66.2447C66.4561 66.2447 64.8701 64.6586 64.8701 62.7201C64.8701 62.4029 64.9229 62.068 65.0463 61.6803L65.1873 61.2045L59.4774 56.9221L59.0545 57.2041C58.4729 57.5918 57.8032 57.8033 57.0983 57.8033C56.4639 57.8033 55.8119 57.6094 55.2479 57.257L54.825 56.9926L46.1545 63.9361L46.3131 64.4119C46.4541 64.8172 46.5246 65.1873 46.5246 65.5574C46.5246 67.4959 44.9385 69.082 43 69.082ZM43 63.4426C41.8369 63.4426 40.8852 64.3943 40.8852 65.5574C40.8852 66.7205 41.8369 67.6721 43 67.6721C44.1631 67.6721 45.1147 66.7205 45.1147 65.5574C45.1147 64.3943 44.1631 63.4426 43 63.4426ZM17.6229 63.4426C16.4598 63.4426 15.5082 64.3943 15.5082 65.5574C15.5082 66.7205 16.4598 67.6721 17.6229 67.6721C18.786 67.6721 19.7377 66.7205 19.7377 65.5574C19.7377 64.3943 18.786 63.4426 17.6229 63.4426ZM68.377 60.6229C67.2139 60.6229 66.2623 61.5746 66.2623 62.7377C66.2623 63.9008 67.2139 64.8525 68.377 64.8525C69.5401 64.8525 70.4918 63.9008 70.4918 62.7377C70.4918 61.5746 69.5401 60.6229 68.377 60.6229ZM30.3114 54.9836C29.1483 54.9836 28.1967 55.9352 28.1967 57.0984C28.1967 58.2615 29.1483 59.2131 30.3114 59.2131C31.4746 59.2131 32.4262 58.2615 32.4262 57.0984C32.4262 55.9352 31.4746 54.9836 30.3114 54.9836ZM57.0983 52.1639C55.9352 52.1639 54.9836 53.1156 54.9836 54.2787C54.9836 55.4418 55.9352 56.3934 57.0983 56.3934C58.2614 56.3934 59.2131 55.4418 59.2131 54.2787C59.2131 53.1156 58.2614 52.1639 57.0983 52.1639Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M14.0983 49.3443V31.0164H35.2459V49.3443H14.0983ZM15.5082 47.9344H33.836V32.4262H15.5082V47.9344Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M29.6065 36.6557H19.7377V38.0656H29.6065V36.6557Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M29.6065 42.2951H19.7377V43.7049H29.6065V42.2951Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M40.8853 45.1148H39.4754V46.5246H40.8853V45.1148Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M71.9016 45.1148H45.1148V46.5246H71.9016V45.1148Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы добавляете SVG файл в HTML страничку

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="css/image/Vector.svg"></object>`

Но это объект, поэтому вы не сможете напрямую стилизовать входящие в него  элементы SVG.

В этом файле SVG могут находиться несколько объектов SVG, у каждого должен быть свой `ID`
Такая структура называется спрайтом. 
Вызываются отдельные элементы с помощью тега `<use>`

```
<use xlink:href="css/image/Vector.svg#pribor"/>
```

Теперь становится возможным стилизовать элементы SVG, либо напрямую

`<use class="use1" xlink:href="css/image/Vector.svg#pribor" fill="red"/>`

Либо через таблицу стилей

```
.use1 {
fill:black;
}
.use1:hover {
fill:red;
}
```

Но всегда нужно помнить, что стили представления (стили, которые находятся внутри svg спрайта) всегда выше по приоритету, чем стили таблицы CSS.

Поэтому лучше предварительно удалить стили в файле SVG.

При работе со спрайтами может возникнуть много нюансов. Поэтому по изучайте вопросы и ответы из соответствующей метки - [svg-спрайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82)

**Если вы не планируете использовать анимацию SVG, стилизацию с помощью правил CSS:** `fill`  `stroke`, `stroke-width` стили шрифтов и многое другое, то можно использовать другие методики добавления SVG в качестве фонового изображения:

### `<img>`

`<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32441.svg">`

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/989409/28748

### `background-image`

```html
<style>
 .container {
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
 background-image:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32441.svg);
   }
</style>
<div class="container"></div>
```

### `content`

```html
<style>
 .container {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
 content: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/32/32443.svg);
   }
</style>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
span:hover path {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="86" height="86" viewBox="0 0 86 86" fill="none">
<path d="M9.86884 78.9508H8.459V80.3607H9.86884V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M15.5082 78.9508H14.0983V80.3607H15.5082V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M21.1475 78.9508H19.7377V80.3607H21.1475V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M77.541 78.9508H67.6722V80.3607H77.541V78.9508Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M6.34426 86C2.8373 86 0 83.1627 0 79.6557V73.3115H2.81967V26.082C2.81967 22.575 5.65697 19.7377 9.16393 19.7377H33.8361V19.0328C33.8361 8.52951 42.3656 0 52.8689 0C63.3721 0 71.9016 8.52951 71.9016 19.0328V19.7377H76.8361C80.343 19.7377 83.1803 22.575 83.1803 26.082V73.3115H86V79.6557C86 83.1627 83.1627 86 79.6557 86H6.34426ZM1.40984 79.6557C1.40984 82.3697 3.63033 84.5902 6.34426 84.5902H79.6557C82.3697 84.5902 84.5902 82.3697 84.5902 79.6557V74.7213H76.1311V26.7869H70.2275L70.0336 27.1922C68.5004 30.3996 66.1213 33.1135 63.143 35.0344C60.0766 37.0258 56.5344 38.0656 52.8689 38.0656C49.2033 38.0656 45.6611 37.0258 42.5947 35.0344C39.6164 33.1135 37.2197 30.3996 35.7041 27.1922L35.5102 26.7869H9.86885V73.3115H32.0209L32.2324 73.5229C33.9242 75.2148 36.1623 76.1311 38.5414 76.1311H47.4762C49.8553 76.1311 52.0934 75.1971 53.7852 73.5229L53.9967 73.3115H71.9016V74.7213H54.5783L54.3844 74.8975C52.4988 76.607 50.0492 77.541 47.4939 77.541H38.559C36.0037 77.541 33.5541 76.607 31.6684 74.8975L31.4746 74.7213H1.40984V79.6557ZM71.6902 21.7467C71.5492 22.716 71.3553 23.6324 71.1086 24.4607L70.8443 25.3594H75.4262C76.5893 25.3594 77.541 26.3111 77.541 27.4742V73.2939H81.7705V26.082C81.7705 23.368 79.55 21.1475 76.8361 21.1475H71.7607L71.6902 21.7467ZM9.16393 21.1475C6.45 21.1475 4.22951 23.368 4.22951 26.082V73.3115H8.45902V27.4918C8.45902 26.3287 9.41066 25.377 10.5738 25.377H34.9111L34.6467 24.4783C34.4 23.6324 34.2061 22.7512 34.0652 21.7643L33.9771 21.1652H9.16393V21.1475ZM36.0918 13.6402C35.5279 15.4025 35.2459 17.2176 35.2459 19.0328C35.2459 28.743 43.1586 36.6557 52.8689 36.6557C54.2258 36.6557 55.618 36.4795 57.0279 36.1447L57.768 35.9684L52.3049 19.5615L36.3385 12.9L36.0918 13.6402ZM53.6795 19.2266L59.1074 35.5279L59.8123 35.2283C66.2975 32.4262 70.4918 26.082 70.4918 19.0328C70.4918 14.8914 69.0115 10.8381 66.3152 7.66598L65.8217 7.08443L53.6795 19.2266ZM52.8689 1.40984C46.2779 1.40984 40.2861 5.05779 37.2373 10.9262L36.8848 11.6135L52.7102 18.2045L64.8348 6.07992L64.2533 5.58648C61.0635 2.89016 57.0102 1.40984 52.8689 1.40984Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M43 69.082C41.0614 69.082 39.4754 67.4959 39.4754 65.5574C39.4754 65.293 39.5106 65.0111 39.5987 64.6938L39.7221 64.218L32.8139 59.6184L32.4086 59.918C31.7918 60.3762 31.0692 60.6229 30.3114 60.6229C29.5537 60.6229 28.8311 60.3762 28.2143 59.918L27.809 59.6184L20.9008 64.218L21.0242 64.6938C21.1123 65.0111 21.1475 65.293 21.1475 65.5574C21.1475 67.4959 19.5614 69.082 17.6229 69.082C15.6844 69.082 14.0983 67.4959 14.0983 65.5574C14.0983 63.6189 15.6844 62.0328 17.6229 62.0328C18.3807 62.0328 19.1033 62.2795 19.7201 62.7377L20.1254 63.0373L27.0336 58.4377L26.9102 57.9619C26.8221 57.6447 26.7869 57.3627 26.7869 57.0984C26.7869 55.1598 28.3729 53.5738 30.3114 53.5738C32.25 53.5738 33.836 55.1598 33.836 57.0984C33.836 57.3627 33.8008 57.627 33.7127 57.9619L33.5893 58.4377L40.4975 63.0373L40.9028 62.7377C41.5196 62.2795 42.2598 62.0328 43 62.0328C43.6344 62.0328 44.2864 62.2266 44.8504 62.5791L45.2733 62.8434L53.9438 55.9L53.7852 55.4242C53.6442 55.0189 53.5737 54.6488 53.5737 54.2787C53.5737 52.3402 55.1598 50.7541 57.0983 50.7541C59.0369 50.7541 60.6229 52.3402 60.6229 54.2787C60.6229 54.5959 60.5701 54.9307 60.4467 55.3184L60.3057 55.7943L66.0155 60.0766L66.4385 59.7947C67.0201 59.407 67.6897 59.1955 68.3946 59.1955C70.3332 59.1955 71.9192 60.7816 71.9192 62.7201C71.9192 64.6586 70.3332 66.2447 68.3946 66.2447C66.4561 66.2447 64.8701 64.6586 64.8701 62.7201C64.8701 62.4029 64.9229 62.068 65.0463 61.6803L65.1873 61.2045L59.4774 56.9221L59.0545 57.2041C58.4729 57.5918 57.8032 57.8033 57.0983 57.8033C56.4639 57.8033 55.8119 57.6094 55.2479 57.257L54.825 56.9926L46.1545 63.9361L46.3131 64.4119C46.4541 64.8172 46.5246 65.1873 46.5246 65.5574C46.5246 67.4959 44.9385 69.082 43 69.082ZM43 63.4426C41.8369 63.4426 40.8852 64.3943 40.8852 65.5574C40.8852 66.7205 41.8369 67.6721 43 67.6721C44.1631 67.6721 45.1147 66.7205 45.1147 65.5574C45.1147 64.3943 44.1631 63.4426 43 63.4426ZM17.6229 63.4426C16.4598 63.4426 15.5082 64.3943 15.5082 65.5574C15.5082 66.7205 16.4598 67.6721 17.6229 67.6721C18.786 67.6721 19.7377 66.7205 19.7377 65.5574C19.7377 64.3943 18.786 63.4426 17.6229 63.4426ZM68.377 60.6229C67.2139 60.6229 66.2623 61.5746 66.2623 62.7377C66.2623 63.9008 67.2139 64.8525 68.377 64.8525C69.5401 64.8525 70.4918 63.9008 70.4918 62.7377C70.4918 61.5746 69.5401 60.6229 68.377 60.6229ZM30.3114 54.9836C29.1483 54.9836 28.1967 55.9352 28.1967 57.0984C28.1967 58.2615 29.1483 59.2131 30.3114 59.2131C31.4746 59.2131 32.4262 58.2615 32.4262 57.0984C32.4262 55.9352 31.4746 54.9836 30.3114 54.9836ZM57.0983 52.1639C55.9352 52.1639 54.9836 53.1156 54.9836 54.2787C54.9836 55.4418 55.9352 56.3934 57.0983 56.3934C58.2614 56.3934 59.2131 55.4418 59.2131 54.2787C59.2131 53.1156 58.2614 52.1639 57.0983 52.1639Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M14.0983 49.3443V31.0164H35.2459V49.3443H14.0983ZM15.5082 47.9344H33.836V32.4262H15.5082V47.9344Z" fill="red"/>
<path d="M29.6065 36.6557H19.7377V38.0656H29.6065V36.6557Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M29.6065 42.2951H19.7377V43.7049H29.6065V42.2951Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M40.8853 45.1148H39.4754V46.5246H40.8853V45.1148Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
<path d="M71.9016 45.1148H45.1148V46.5246H71.9016V45.1148Z" fill="#4E4E4E"/>
</svg>
</span>
```

**UPD.**

```css
.icon-bike:hover {
  filter: invert(27%) sepia(51%) saturate(2878%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(104%) contrast(97%);
}
```

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/icon-bike-black.svg" class="icon icon-bike">
    Bike
  </object>
```

Comment: Это работает только если вставлять именно svg. А я хочу сократить количество кода и использовать object что бы загружать уже созданные svg файлы. В таком случае можно что-то сделать?

Comment: @Zoom, обновил ()

Comment: Спасибо ! А нет сайтов, где можно получить значения фильтров для получения определенного цвета? К примеру  мне нужен #009091

Comment: @Zoom, есть, [вот](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

Comment: @Zoom выбирая решение стилизовать с помощью фильтров мне кажется вы делаете ошибку. Так как теряются основные преимущества SVG - нет адаптивности, нет интерактивности. В этом случае он ничем не отличается от растровых изображений поставленных фоном. Окраску с помощью фильтров применяют от безисходности, когда имеют дело с псевдо SVG (формат base64) и нет других способов, кроме фильтров стилизовать изображение.